# FreeMarker how to find corresponding java classes

Tags: java, freemarker

I am investigating large project that uses FreeMarker. I am newbie to FreeMarker. How I can find which classes of java are used to receive values for templates? Investigate all project seems enormous work.
Thanks.
May be need some plugins for Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FreeMarker is a typical "dynamic language", which means refactoring/changing is hard. The templates don't declare what they expect to be in the data-model. Furthermore, when a template tries to read a value from the data-model, like with `${foo.bar}`, it could mean `foo.get("bar")` or `foo.getBar()` or whatever the `ObjectWrapper` used makes possible, and it's only decided when the template is executed. Certainly you will need to fall back to good-old search-and-replace and lot of testing (a good test suite is essential...) if you change something. And of course, you could look at the place in the program where the data-model is built, and see what was put into it. Or dump the data-model somehow on runtime.

Comment: Though editors like Intellij Idea does have support to annotate the type of vars in comment and makes refactoring possible/easy.

Comment: Good point. In bigger projects it's a good idea to put comments into the templates about the expected variables anyway, but if the IDE understands that, that's even better. Of course, the main problem with these comments is that nothing guarantees that they remain in sync with the reality...